# gtkmm changing toggle button state without invoking signal

Tags: radio-button, gtk, signals, togglebutton, gtkmm

I'm trying to make multiple Gtk::ToggleButton's to act as Gtk::RadioButton's. When one of the buttons is pressed that other switch off.

It would be as simple as creating a switch statement if Gtk::ToggleButton didn't handle switching (pressed or not pressed) on its own.

So, I'm planning to handle it's switching as regular button with calling signal_clicked().connect() which calls for function set_active(true/false) which makes button look pressed or not pressed.

Here is example of what I'm trying to do:

Event calls when button is clicked:

```
//enum {infoState, artState, editState, userState, exitState}; is initialised in header 

artButt.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::bind<short int>(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &fooclass::toggleButton), artButt));  
editButt.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::bind<short int>(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &fooclass::toggleButton), editButt));
```

Toggling button:

```
void fooClass::toggleButton()
{
//oldState and enum {infoState, artState, editState, userState, exitState}; are initialised in header
if(oldState != newState)
{   
    //disable old togglebutton
    switch (oldState)
        {
            case infoState:
                infoButt.set_active(false);
            break;
            case artState:
                artButt.set_active(false);
            break;
            case editState:
                editButt.set_active(false);
            break;
            case userState:
                userButt.set_active(false);
            break;
        }

        //enable new one
        switch (newState)
        {
            case infoState:
                userButt.set_active(false);
            break;
            case artState:
                artButt.set_active(true);
            break;
            case editState:
                editButt.set_active(true);
            break;
            case userState:
                userButt.set_active(true);
            break;
        }
        oldState = newState;
}    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use`Gtk::RadioButton` directly. With the `draw-indicator` property you can make them look like regular toggle buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is my workaround. There is probably better way, so please if you know any post it here:

Firstly use Gtk::Button instead of Gtk::ToggleButton .

Secondly instead of set_active() use set_state_flags(). Gtk::STATE_FLAG_CHECKED when you want it to be enabled and GTK::STATE_FLAGS_NORMAL when you want it to be disabled.

So, this is how code should look like:

```
void Window::changeState()
{
    if(oldState != state)
    {
        //delete old state
        switch (oldState)
        {
            case infoState:
                infoButt.set_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_NORMAL);
            break;
            case artState:
                artButt.set_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_NORMAL);
            break;
            case editState:
                editButt.set_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_NORMAL);
            break;
            case userState:
                userButt.set_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_NORMAL);
            break;
        }
        //move to new state
        switch (state)
        {
            case infoState:          
                infoButt.set_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_CHECKED);
            break;
            case artState:
                artButt.set_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_CHECKED);
            break;
            case editState:
                head.editButt.set_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_CHECKED);
            break;
            case userState:
                userButt.set_state_flags(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_CHECKED);
            break;

            case exitState:
                close();
            break;
        }

        show_all_children();
        oldState = state;

    }
}
```